# How to browse all files in a specific directory?

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript to build some app, that needs to list and present all files in the phone's gallery. I cannot use any "image picker": It just needs to present the user with all existing images,  but doing so **through the app**.

I was told to use this:

> android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

But this just returns a string "Pictures".

How do i actually access this directory? What Android class deals with "browsing" built-in directories?

The documentation contains countless classes. Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: `new File(dirPath).list();` get all files as string array of paths in that directory.

Comment: Thank you nick. This seems to be some globally available class in Java. Do you by any chance know how to access it through Nativescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of `Folder` from the absolute path and use `.getEntities()` method to read list of files / folders within the particular folder.

```
import { Folder } from "tns-core-modules/file-system";

const androidPicturesPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
).toString();

const folder = Folder.fromPath(androidPicturesPath);

folder.getEntities()
    .then((entities) => {
        // entities is an array of files and folders.
        entities.forEach((entity) => {
           console.log(entity.name);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        // Failed to obtain folder's contents.
        console.log(err);
    });
```

***Note*:** Make sure your app has **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission, use [nativescript-permissions](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions/) plugin to acquire the permission at run time.